# In AFNetworking's JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure: method, what type of object is the JSON response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, afjsonrequestoperation

It gives you a variable called JSON of type id, but how do I manipulate this? Is it a string? Do I have to serialize it first? How exactly do I interact with it?

Comment: This might help [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473811/afnetworking-and-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returned in the form of dictionary, you just need to extract the value based on the key. Example :

`[JSON valueForKey:@"key"];`

Answer (score 0):

You can get more than the basics
[here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/)

Fantastic course, there's very good code about json handling in the photo mania app.